# Any known cases of government backdoors creating exploitable security holes?

Tags: backdoor, government

As the Apple v FBI battle unfolds, government backdoors will become a hot topic. As background to that, I have two questions:

- Are there any known cases where governments have forced tech companies to introduce backdoors into their products? (I'm not talking about accidental security holes that governments have been able to exploit, nor am I talking about companies simply handing over unencrypted data in their posession.)
- Are there any cases where a government backdoor have been exploited by other actors, or information on how to use it has become publicly available, thereby creating a serious security threat to the users of the product?

I am interested in examples from all around the world, both new and old. Basically what I want to have is examples to use as an efficient rebuttal to the argument "Well, a backdoor only the government knows about couldn't possibly hurt anyone."

Comment: These things are very hard to prove. Highly suspect case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_BSAFE

Comment: Big LOL at "Well, a backdoor only the government knows about couldn't possibly hurt anyone." [Government employees lose laptops with sensitive data monthly.](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20070212/130314.shtml) I am heavily suspect that they would treat this backdoor any differently. Ok, I'm done ranting.

Comment: I once heard that the government managed to get a backdoor into PGP, but it seems to be a false rumor. Still, if you obtain your copy precompiled, you can't be sure it matches the publicly available source code (which has been thoroughly scrutinized by the encryption community).

Comment: Would appreciate some guidance on what makes this question to broad, and how it could be narrowed down. In essence it is two yes or no questions, together with a request for examples. Is it inherently OT to ask for examples, since there could be many? I think Steffen Ullrich answer shows that this question can indeed be consisly answered.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

- [Wiretapping case in Greece 2004–05](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_wiretapping_case_2004%E2%80%9305): officially mandated but disabled interface for tapping into talks was used by unknown entity to listen to talks by high-profile politicians.
- [Juniper VPN Backdoor](http://www.wired.com/2015/12/juniper-networks-hidden-backdoors-show-the-risk-of-government-backdoors/): use of NSA mandated insecure random generator together with the modifications added by an unknown party allowed decryption of VPN traffic by third parties by simple passive sniffing.
- [Backdoor in the cryptography of Lotus Notes used by several european governments](http://www.heise.de/tp/artikel/2/2898/1.html). While they got the version with stronger cryptography the NSA controlled part of the key so in effect they got a version where NSA could still decrypt the content.
- Government mandated export regulations lead to the EXPORT ciphers in SSL. These ciphers were used outside the USA because the stronger ciphers could not be exported. While this was long ago the ciphers are still there and ultimately lead to the [FREAK attack](https://freakattack.com/).
- [GCHQ forced weak cryptography into the GSM standard](http://www.aftenposten.no/nyheter/uriks/Sources-We-were-pressured-to-weaken-the-mobile-security-in-the-80s-7413285.html) so that they could decrypt mobile communication.

Comment: +1 for the export ciphers. Absolutely the first thing that came to mind before I even actually read the question.

Comment: How does the Greek wiretapping case count as government backdoor? A spy (so it seems) managed to install rogue software because of phone operator's negligence, and possibly corruption. Greek government didn't mandate them to do it, nor did it force the operator to install the rogue code.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev  the Greek government mandated that the ability to tap a line existed on the switch.  The hacker installed their own illegal tap into the gov mandated backdoor

Comment: @JRaymond: it was actually more complex. The tapping interface is an international standard because all the governments like to tap some calls. This interface was not needed in Greece but since it was standard in the software it was still in the firmware although disabled. Somebody unknown enabled it and used it for tapping the calls. But in the end somebody used a backdoor which was added for the governments only.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I believe a tap is conceptually different from a backdoor. If I break a server and steal the logs, will I be using a "backdoor" created by Debian?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev your analogy is not equivalent. The tap is a backdoor into the phonecall, it just so happens that they also breached a system to get access to the backdoor.

Comment: @JamesRyan a backdoor has to be essential to gain access. When you install rogue software on a switch, you get all the access you need. You can just as well implement call routing yourself, the tap function here is merely a convenience which does call routing for you.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: the tap functionality is a government mandated backdoor into a phone call. It is not simply a software feature to enhance the call because it is explicitly designed to be undetectable by the parties of the phone call.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I didn't get that. Are you saying the tap functionality is not implemented in software?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: Of course the tap is software. But it is not what I would call simply a software feature. Other backdoors are software too and I would also not call them simply a software feature, because they are only there because the government requested these backdoors.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich No, a backdoor is something that gains you access where you don't have access to otherwise. I don't see how tapping facility on a system under your control qualifies. `tee` is also software, and it can tap into pipes. Would you call it a backdoor?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: I agree that a backdoor is something that gains you access where you don't have access to otherwise. Thus a tap is a backdoor into a call because without it the government would not have access to the call. It's not a backdoor into the switch, but a backdoor into the call.